# Intel XDK download link not working inside iframe

Tags: intel, intel-xdk

Download link not working inside iframe after building android mobile application using intel xdk. In emulator the download link working after building it's not working.
any one know solution for my problem plz reply.

Comment: check your whitelist settings

Comment: add **http://*** to Intent(External Whitelist) but still that download link not working after building android app

Comment: can u post your code?

Comment: Try doing a Crosswalk build.  I just tried regular android vs crosswalk, and the latter worked while the former didn't.  I haven't tried inside an iframe yet, but give Crosswalk a try and see what happens.

Comment: I also added the File Transfer plugin to make sure the permissions for downloading were correct.

Comment: @OldGeeksGuide Tried on building android crosswalk application on this time after installing app on mobile when open app it shows only blank screen

Comment: Please provide any other solutions

Comment: There is not enough iformation here to know what the problem is.  I'd recommend you try the debugger to see what's happening.  Or you could try posting on the Intel XDK Forums - https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk - and provide a sample that shows the problem you're seeing.  You may also need to look into the `sandbox` attribute - http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-sandbox

Comment: Already posted in intel xdk forum no solution provided.

Comment: i will post my sample code